# Oracle REGEX functions

Tags: regex, oracle

I am working on Oracle 10gR2.

I am working on a column which stores username. Let's say that one of the values in this column is "Ankur". I want to fetch all records where username is a concatenated string of "Ankur" followed by some numerical digits, like "Ankur1", "Ankur2", "Ankur345" and so on. I do not want to get records with values such as "Ankurab1" - that is anything which is concatenation of some characters to my input string.

I tried to use REGEX functions to achieve the desired result, but am not able to.

I was trying:

```
SELECT 1 FROM dual WHERE regexp_like ('Ankur123', '^Ankur[:digit:]$');
```

Can anyone help me here?

Comment: I was trying REGEX_LIKE `SELECT 1 FROM dual WHERE regexp_like ('Ankur123', '^Ankur[:digit:]$');`

Comment: This does not work, as I believe REGEX_ functions only expect wild card characters and patterns for matching and evaluating expressions. I am clueless as to how I can pass on a defined value and then specify wild card characters for a match

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Oracle uses POSIX EREs](http://www.regular-expressions.info/oracle.html) (which don't support the common `\d` shorthand), so you can use

```
^Ankur[0-9]+$
```

Your version would nearly have worked, too:

```
^Ankur[[:digit:]]+$
```

One set of `[...]` for the character class, and one for the `[:digit:]` subset. And of course a `+` to allow more than just one digit.

Answer (score 3):

You were close

Try `regexp_like ('Ankur123', '^Ankur[[:digit:]]+$')` instead.

Note the `[[` instead of the single `[` and the `+` in front of the `$`.

Without the `+` the regexp only matches for exactly *one* digit after the String *Ankur*.